# Logging each expect statement to console

Tags: node.js, jasmine, protractor

Using Protractor I am testing my web app. For a story I need to write some text message to console so that can review it later. Currently doing like this

```
expect(element.isPresent()).toBe(true);
console.log('Create button is present');
```

later when running the suits, using command

```
protractor conf.js > testLog.txt
```

in testLog.txt file I can see my console statements. Is there any way to avoid that extra call of console.log? So whenever expect is called I can pass some text message too to output in console.

Comment: Do you mean you want to include custom message in the `expect` expression somehow, so you would have one line of code instead of two?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be reinventing the wheel here. The use case really fits the *[Behavior Driven Development](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavior-driven_development)* pattern - basically you would have your tests described in a human language (including the expectations via "then"):

```
Feature: Running Cucumber with Protractor
  As a user of Protractor
  I should be able to use Cucumber
  to run my E2E tests

  Scenario: Wrapping WebDriver
    Given I go on "index.html"
    Then the title should equal "My AngularJS App"
```

See how to use [`cucumber.js`](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js) BDD framework with protractor:

- [Functional testing with cucumber and protractor](http://nicholasjackson.github.io/agile/bdd/angular/protractor/cucumber/protractor-cucumber/)
- [Acceptance testing with Cucumber.js and Protractor](http://stuff.aftnn.org/acceptance-testing-cucumber.js-protractor/#1)
- [protractor-cucumber](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-cucumber)